# Service Fabric Reliable Collections: serialization issue

Tags: c#, serialization, collections, deserialization, azure-service-fabric

Reliable Collection (Queue) values store some complex type `SomeUnit`.

I've marked it as `[DataContract]` and it's members as `[DataMember]` and added `[KnownType(typeof(SomeUnit))]` attribute on top of it also.

Looks like now SomeUnit serializes, but then deserialize exception is thrown:

> Element 'urn:ServiceFabric.Communication:item' contains data from a
>   type that maps to the name
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RP.Core:SomeUnit'. The
>   deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using
>   DataContractSerializer or add the type corresponding to 'SomeUnit' to
>   the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you share a [simple but complete code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?  As it is, it's hard to know the problem.  Are you constructing the `DataContractSerializer` differently when serializing vs deserializing?  Are you using different classes when deserializing, or the same classes?

Comment: @dbc, there are Azure Service Fabric specifics in this question. I don't have a deal with `DataContractSerializer` itself in this case. One reliable service creating an object of type `SomeUnit`. And then trying to enqueue into other reliable service's reliable queue. Exception thrown here. Looks like second service cannot deserialize object, serialized by first service. But both services reference class library that contains `SomeUnit`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are not showing any code we can only guess what's causing this.

This problem would occur if you would use a reliable queue with a generalized item type, for example a base class of `SomeUnit`.

```
// Using reliable collection with a base item type
IReliableQueue<BaseClass> myQueue = ...;

// Store derived item in the queue
SomeUnit myData = ...; // SomeUnit inherit from BaseClass
await myQueue.EnqueueAsync(txn, myData); // OK to store but won't deserialize!
```

The deserializer for that queue would know how to parse `BaseClass` but it won't be implicitly aware of your derived class `SomeUnit`.

You can fix that by applying a `KnownTypeAttribute` on the base class, thereby explicitly declaring the derived classes that the deserializer shall be aware of.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SomeUnit))]
public class BaseClass
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class SomeUnit : BaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

---

It's not possible to apply [KnownType] on an interface type. There are, however, some options for supporting this:

#### Option #1

Use a wrapper contract to declare known type(s).

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SomeUnit))]
public class Wrapper
{
    [DataMember]
    public IUnit Value { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SomeUnit : IUnit
{
    ...
}
```

#### Option #2

Specify known types to the [DataContractSerializer constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344259(v=vs.110).aspx).

This will, however, require that you [tell service fabric to use your custom serializer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-serialization/).

#### Option #3

Specify known types in a configuration file (app.config) as [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5).

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I was not able to track SO last week. That's exactly what my case, except I'm trying to use interface instead base class. But it is not possible to mark interface with `KnownType` attribute. Is there any trick to achieve this?

Comment: @AsValeO: Please see my recent edit for options on how to do this for interface types.

Comment: Wrapper works well! Thank for your full and detailed answer!

Comment: If you want to use generic types in the app config, this link is useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/declaredtypes

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit of an old topic but after having this problem and not wanting to use the KnownType method (as it can get a bit messy if you have a lot of derived types) I was able to sucessfully get my messages serialized with the following use of reflection:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public abstract class Event
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime AtTime { get; private set; }

    public Event()
    {
        AtTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
    {
        return typeof(Event).Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Event)))
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```